# Is the cat figurine thing a problem at kosher Chinese restaurants?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, avodah-zarah, restaurant

It seems like all kosher Chinese restaurants have this cat-statue thingy in the front:

[image: Maneki Neko]

Is there any Halachic problem with that?  I assume not, if they're all kosher-certified; but why not?

Comment: I just looked it up and can't find any references to this in Chinese culture (just Japanese).  I have also never seen it before, despite visiting dozens of Chinese restaurants.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think I've ever seen it, but a quick Wikipedia search on [Maneki Neko](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maneki_Neko) (the title of your image!) reveals that it is some kind of good luck charm. It would definitely seem forbidden for a Jew to use it for that purpose, but I assume most have it there only for the "ambiance" (which might still be problematic, I don't know).

In any event, the kosher certification probably does not cover such issues; it would probably be out of any mashgiach's radar (until he visits mi.yodeya, that is).

Comment: If a chamtza, painting your house blue, or fish  aren't forbidden, then why would this be forbidden?

Comment: Can you offer any support that having a good luck charm is problematic for a Jew, or that Kosher certification shouldn't care if there is 'Avodah Zarah present in the restaurant?

Comment: Some kashrus organizations focus primarily on the food itself and generally leave out the atmosphere, while others take the atmosphere into significant detail. For instance, I know the Star-K won't allow a lack of tznius clothing in their waiters (even non-Jewish run restaurants) or certain music/shows to be played.

Comment: I don't think the issue is AZ, @SethJ. I think the issue is one of "לא תנחשו."

Comment: @shokhet, I understand. My comment was noting lack of support provided in the answer for the assertions within the answer.

Comment: I didn't see anything in the answer about AZ, but I haven't had my coffee yet and may be missing something :) @SethJ

Answer (score 5):

It's not any more of a problem than a khamse is at a North African restaurant. It's a siman for good luck, and not avoda zara. It's only problematic if you reject segulot and other superstitions, like the Rambam does. However, I would question what a JAPANESE cat thing is doing in a CHINESE restaurant!

Comment: [Chinese, Japanese, what's the difference?](http://www.funny.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/Funny.woa/wa/funny?fn=C5PMR&Funny_Jokes=What_s_the_Difference) :)

Comment: The name. If the name is Jim, guess what I am :)?